# GAS code for returning windows login ID

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way of returning the windows user ID, as you can with VBA and Excel, but with GAS for Google Sheets?

I would like to know the windows login of different people using the same goggle account.

This is not the same as the Session object function which returns the Google account user ID.

Any chance?

Comment: rather unlikely - most browsers except IE aren't aware of your local windows logon (by default). And even if Google Sheets sure isn't...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Google Apps Script you should use *something* that has access to the local environment. That *thing* could call Google Apps Script web apps programmed to act as a web services.